# Is there a JQuery version of the ASP.Net AJAX Toolkit Combobox?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-ajax

This is what I'm talking about:
http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/ComboBox/ComboBox.aspx

basically I want to have a drop down list that can also have a manual text override... is there a jquery plugin that can do this easily? Or should I try and incorporate the toolkit one somehow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jEC maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Check these plugins:

- [SexyCombo](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/SexyCombo)
- [QuickSelect](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/quickselect)
- [DropList Filter](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/droplist_filter)

They all work extending the native `SELECT` HTML element, and since the `ASP:DropDownList` is rendered on the client as a `select` element, I think they will work without problems.